# CircleCI deployment to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, circleci

Can you help me find a useful step-by-step guide or a [Gist](https://gist.github.com) outlining in detail how to configure [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) (using 2.0 syntax) to deploy to AWS EC2?

I understand the basic requirements and the moving pieces, but unsure what to put in the `.circleci/config.yml` file in the `deploy` step.

So far I got:

- A "Hello World" [Node.js app](https://github.com/ChristianRich/circleci-aws) which is building successfully in CircleCI (just without the deploy step)
- A running EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04)
- An IAM user with sufficient permissions added to CircleCI for that particular job

Can you help out with the CircleCI deploy step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following your repository, you could create a script just like that: `deploy.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start deploy"
cd ~/circleci-aws
git pull
npm i
npm run build 
pm2 stop build/server
pm2 start build/server
echo "Deploy end"
```

And in your `.circleci/conf.yml` you do it:

```
deploy:
docker:
  - image: circleci/node:chakracore-8.11.1
steps:
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
      - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
  - run:
      name: AWS EC2 deploy
      command: |
        #upload all the code to machine
        scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./ ubuntu@13.236.1.107:/home/circleci-aws/
        #Run script inside of machine
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@13.236.1.107 "./deploy.sh"
```

But this is so ugly, try something like AWS Codedeploy or ecs for using containers.